# How to access inputtext id using $component vf page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a vf page where i need to add 2 fields and show the result in third. I want to do this using javascript by fetching Id of the fields using $component. I tried using this but i am not able to get the Id in javascript..

I am trying to access and add field Id six, seven and show the result in eight..

VF Page -

```
      <apex:page standardController="RFP__c" extensions="RFPController" sidebar="false">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <c:FixSfdcFocusHack />
        <c:JQuery />
        <c:Chosen />
        <script language="javascript">
    function itschanged(){
    var selval1 = document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb.section.thetable.six.sp}').value;
    var selval2 = document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb.section.thetable.seven.pg}').value;
    var selval3 = document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb.section.thetable.eight.tn}').value;

    if(selval1 == 'NA')
    selval1 = '0';
    if(selval2 == 'NA')
    selval2 = '0';

    document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb.section.thetable.eight.tn}').value = Number(selval1) + Number(selval2) ;
    }
</script>;
        <style>
       .twitterStyleTextbox {
        border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
        width: 180px;
        height: 18px;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    }

    .twitterStyleTextbox:focus {
        outline: none;
        border: 1px solid #7bc1f7;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
    }
     </style>
    <apex:form id="myForm">
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
    <apex:pageMessages />
          <apex:outputText rendered="{!isRerender}">
          </apex:outputText>      
          <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}"/>
          <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" id="section">
            <apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable"  var="acc" value="{!attendeeList1}" onRowMouseOver="removeHighlight(this)">
              <apex:column id="six" headerValue="Space Discount">
             <apex:inputtext value="{!acc.spacediscount}" styleClass="twitterStyleTextbox" onchange="itschanged();" id="sp"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column id="seven" headerValue="Per Unit Gross Rate">
              <apex:inputtext value="{!acc.perunitgross}" styleClass="twitterStyleTextbox" onchange="itschanged();" id="pg"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column id="eight" headerValue="Total Net">
              <apex:inputtext value="{!acc.totalnet}" styleClass="twitterStyleTextbox" id="tn"/>
              </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

[image]
Regards

Comment: you are using  '{!$Component.myForm.six} to get vaue but there is no input textbox with six as id. that is column id in your code that is why you are not able to get value. make that id for inputtext textbox

Comment: Hi ... I corrected by above code....Can u please chk.. I am not able to get still..

Comment: it will be '{!$Component.myForm.pb.section.thetable.six.sp}

Comment: Corrected the above code.. Still no success...

Comment: if not necessary then you can reference them by class name or jquery selecter.

Comment: what is the error your are getting ?

Comment: No error....Let me try once again..

Comment: you are calling this function on onChanged event so once you will move cursor out from textbox you will see value.

Comment: i believe javascript is not firing....

Comment: I have updated by post with image.. wht i am trying to achieve...

Comment: very what id SFDC is generating. alert('{!$Component.myForm.pb.section.thetable.six.sp}'); and match this value with textbox id. by right click on textbox and inspect element

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because your `html` is being rendered in a separate `iFrame` by VF. You can verify this by doing inspect element on your VF page.

Now, to answer your question:

To access the elements inside an `iFrame` you will have to access the `document` object inside the `iFrame` by doing,

`document.getElementById('contentPane').contentWindow.document`

`contentPane` is the `id` of the `iFrame` generated by your VF page.

After doing this, you can access your elements normally by doing something like,

`document.getElementById('contentPane').contentWindow.document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb.section.thetable.eight.tn}')`